# Connecting my two installs of minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, windows-7, linux

I have a dual-boot PC, one has windows and one has Linux. They both have minecraft, and I've like them to share the same savegame/server data.

Is this possible, and if so how do I set it up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use pendrive to hold savedata, you can use [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com/), or make a symlink to the windows partition on Linux.

For example:

> ln -s /mnt/windows/Users/Pureferret/.minecraft/saves ~/.minecraft/saves

Comment: The symlink sounds like what I want. Can I do likewise but in reverse (windows<-linux)? I don't want to face backup issues when connecting to a pendrive or Dropbox.

Comment: Not really, because you can easily access Windows from Linux, because of the drivers built-in kernel. For accessing Linux from Windows, you need special software, and can't really do it easily, and no hope for symlinks either. You just need to make sure your Windows partition is always mounted in same place, like /mnt/windows, because Ubuntu and other distributions like to make folders named as drive's GUID, like /media/U34JAN2-SMK2SJ stuff.

Comment: @Maxorq: Starting with Vista, Windows support [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) exactly like Linux - you still need [a driver](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) to mount the file system, but other than that, you *can* indeed do it in reverse.

Comment: @MichaelMadsen Windows 2k also had something like symlinks, of course, I didn't say that there are no symbolic links in Windows, but the problem is with drivers. Linux have drivers out-of-box, and for Windows you need to find them by yourself :(

Comment: this is what I use and it's effective, but: I had two or three times corrupted games files, not sure if it's because of NTFS, or hibernation or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I know a method with the new launcher which works both ways.

1. Boot into **LINUX** and start minecraft.
2. Edit the profiles to point to the windows hard drive (Ex: from ~/.minecraft/saves **to** C:/Users/Username/Appdata/Roaming/.minecraft/saves)
   3.Save the profile
3. ...
4. Profit.

Just a little note: If you use the grub bootloader and you leave windows hibernating, then boot linux you cannot play your saves. I don't know why you would do that, but i just happened to forget windows was on and boot Ubuntu this morning. I had trouble making the windows path from earlier because Ubuntu refused to see the windows partition.

Comment: Will not work: C: means nothing to Linux